# Where to place zsh autocompletion script on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

After installing [`cheat` (command cheat sheets from the command line)](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat), I tried to enable the autocompletion using the [provided zsh script](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat#enabling-command-line-autocompletion). However, I don't seem to find the correct location for the script.

#### So far

- I fetch the `cheat.zsh` ;
- copy it to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/cheat/_cheat.zsh` ;
- add the *cheat* to the `plugins` array in my `~/.zshrc` ;
- reload my shell.

Auto-completion doesn't happen when typing `cheat d<TAB>`.

### Question

So where to place zsh auto-completion script on Linux?

Comment: try adding it to ~/.bash_profile.. like 'source .oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/cheat/_cheat.zsh'

Comment: @Maximin: He is using Zsh, not Bash.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got this to work by adding `cheat.zsh` to the `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins` directory. Zsh checks to autoload functions on `FPATH`, so try:

```
echo $FPATH
```

and then either add to `FPATH` or move the file into a folder on the path.

This actually does a much better job of explaining it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/how-to-define-and-load-your-own-shell-function-in-zsh

Comment: I don't got `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/cheat/` in the `$FPATH` however I got another cutsom plugin. So I guess my `source $HOME/.zshrc` isn't enough.

Answer (score 14):

Let me try to help here.

I was trying something similar and this is how I was able to get it worked.
Below solution has verified with `oh-my-zsh` on debian distro [ubuntu]

### Problem

```
  > Your zsh isnt giving proper completion suggestions say [conda]
  > This is what you get when you type in # conda tab
```

[image]

### Solution

1. Find the completion script

   one great location is https://github.com/clarketm/zsh-completions/tree/master/src
2. Download the file to completions folder `[~/.oh-my-zsh/completions]`

   ```sh
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/zsh-completions/master/src/_conda ~/.oh-my-zsh/completions
   ```
3. Make sure the completions folder is listed under $fpath

   ```sh
   print -l $fpath
   ```

   1. What if its not listed
      It should have normaly added with .oh-my-zsh.sh
      If not append below to ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh

      ```sh
      # add a function path
      fpath=($ZSH/functions $ZSH/completions $fpath)
      ```
   2. source .zshrc

      ```sh
      source ~/.zshrc
      ```
4. Execute `compinit` this will build `~/.zcompdump` file for the functions

   ```sh
   compinit
   ```

[image]

### Troubleshooting

1. Due to conflicts the suggestions might not be shown try the following

   ```sh
   rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit
   # we are clearing the function dump stored by zsh, its safe zsh will rebuilt it.
   ```
2. Try source `.zshrc`

   ```sh
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```
3. Try loggin out and login
4. Check the mapping in `~/.zcompdump`

   ```sh
   vi ~/.zcompdump
   ```

   search for conda

   `[/conda]`

   you should see as below

   `'conda' '_conda'`

Hope someone will find it useful, if so Happy to Help

Comment: I was adding a completion script and I found that the filename had **dash/hyphen** in it, it was not loaded in the `~/.zcompdump`. After I renamed it to underscore, it was working fine. Please mention it in that too. Another point to mention, if someone does not provide the zsh completion, they can follow this steps https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535646/140177